# Showing a function is convex

Tags: real-analysis

I must show that if $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function, $c \in [a,b]$, then the function $G:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $G(x)=\int_{c}^{x} g(t)dt$ is convex.

Does anyone have ideas on how to do this?
I have previously shown that $f:I = [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex iff for every $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in I$ with $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ we have $$\frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} \leq \frac{f(x_3) - f(x_2)}{x_3 - x_2}$$ Though, i'm not sure how we can apply this to the current exercise

Comment: You want $\frac {G(x_2)-G(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\le \frac {G(x_3)-G(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}.$ That says the average of $g$ is smaller on the first interval than the second, which makes perfect sense because $g$ increases.

Comment: But $g$ is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Then use the simple argument that, since $g$ is nondecreasing, $$\frac{G(x_2)-G(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\leqslant g(x_2)\leqslant\frac{G(x_3)-G(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}.$$